# When to use "I" + is

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, inflectional-morphology, african-american-vernacular-english, pirate-english

Once I saw this sentence in the movie that:
I is in charge of the classroom !

Why after "I" did they use is ?
Is that a metaphor ?
I want to explain my students but could not.

Comment: It's probably a ***facetious*** usage (deliberately ungrammatical, for some context-specific reason), as per TV comic Ali G's [*Is it because I's black?*](https://www.independent.ie/woman/celeb-news/whats-a-nice-jewish-boy-doing-pretending-to-be-black-26252974.html) But a more complete context would be useful here. If nothing else, ***what*** movie? Then we could at least contextualise it from a subtitle file, if not the actual footage.

Comment: You use it when you're being ungrammatical, either on purpose or because it's the culture you inherited.

Comment: Can you tell us what movie, and what the situation was?

Comment: its in the " pirate of caribbean " where Jack says this

Comment: its in the " pirate of caribbean " where jack told this

I think mean I = one = i 

mean one person is going to do that and that person is me

Comment: If you want I can show the scene of the movie

Comment: "I is in charge of the classroom" is in Pirates of the Caribbean??

Comment: (But if you heard it in Pirates of the Caribbean it's because it was [Talk Like a Pirate Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Talk_Like_a_Pirate_Day).)

Comment: In a situation like, 'I' is a vowel, it should work.

Comment: I will share the exact scene in here then you will see just wait for me to cut it out

Comment: You have to consider that it's a joke, to imply that you are a qualified teacher and to prove you are unqualified.

Comment: one said: "I is" is not standard English. The standard English conjugation for "to be" is I am, you are, he/she/it is, we are, they are.

However, you will find "I is" used in AAVE (African American Vernacular English), where the verb "to be" is conjugated almost entirely in standard third-singular (I is, you is, he/she/it is, we is, they is/are). So if you're writing a character who speaks AAVE, it would be entirely correct to use, for example, "I's going to the store" instead of "I am."

Answer (score 0):

If you heard this in "Pirates of the Caribbean", it's because movie pirates typically speak in a non-standard dialect of English. (Actually, pirates didn't talk like this, it has become a stereotype in popular culture, mainly due to how they were portrayed in Disney's "Treasure Island" movie.<sup>[1]</sup>)

You can find similar affectations in the Cockney dialec spoken by Eliza Doolittle in "My Fair Lady". I think this is more true to life, although the characters in the play/movie may be extreme examples of it for dramatic purposes.

[1] ['Pirate Speak' Is A Myth Perpetuated By Disney](https://io9.gizmodo.com/pirate-speak-is-a-myth-perpetuated-by-disney-1636848384)

Comment: Yes maybe you are right 
but I checked the oxford dictionary " I " sometimes indicates 1

Comment: I think that's only when it's used as a Roman numeral.